# Short film with Darth Vader on the subway?

Tags: story-identification, darth-vader, short-film

I'm looking for the name of a short film where Darth Vader chases a kid through a subway station. This would be a late 70's or early 80's film. Probably a student film. It is live-action, not animated.

I've found other people looking for it who say it aired on "HBO Short Takes". But I'm pretty sure I saw it on TVO. I think there is little or no dialogue. At the end of the film it turns out his imagination was playing tricks and the kid is safe.

Any info would be appreciated!

Comment: Someone else is looking for it here, FWIW https://www.kindertrauma.com/name-that-trauma-reader-patrick-j-d-on-darth-vader-rides-the-subway/

Comment: Just imagine a ticket inspector trying to inspect Vader's ticket :P

Comment: @SpacePhoenix what if the inspector is played by Harrison Ford/Han Solo? ["No ticket"](https://youtu.be/s0vNsH81YeA) :P